# how to import matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to run, on IDLE, the following [example code](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html), which was copied from matplotlib's official website:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

But I got lots of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/temp/pyplot_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 23, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 18, in <module>
    from axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.axis as maxis
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 12, in <module>
    import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 1615, in <module>
    class BoxStyle(_Style):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 2068, in BoxStyle
    {"AvailableBoxstyles": _pprint_styles(_style_list)}
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 1539, in _pprint_styles
    args, varargs, varkw, defaults =  inspect.getargspec(cls.__init__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getargspec'
```

My computer is a Windows XP machine. Python and matplotlib (and other site packages such as numpy) were installed cleanly using [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/). Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you happen to have a custom `inspect.py` module lying around?  When you enter `import inspect; inspect`, what does it print?

Comment: Yes. So, there is a name clash. After changing the filename, the code works now. Thanks very much. If you turn the comment into an answer I will flag it as the correct answer.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem, when I run `import inspect; inspect`, I get following output <module 'inspect' from 'C:\Python27\lib\inspect.pyc'>, what does it mean and how to I still import matlibplot for plotting purpose.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek it means that **you did not** have the same problem that OP did.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing `matplotlib.pylab`, as it is alias for `pyplot`.